# Citing MOOCs which cannot be accessed

Tags: citations, mooc

I want to cite a MOOC, but the MOOC is no longer running. The URL I saved only takes me to the course homepage, not the page giving the information I used. Is this acceptable for a reference?
This is the page I end up on, but my citation is linked to peer to peer learning within the MOOC.

Comment: Maybe you no longer have access to course content. If that's the case, you may want to get in touch with the instructors. They should be able to help. Which platform is the MOOC from?  Was the MOOC offered by a university or a tech company or someone else?

Comment: Why would you need to cite a MOOC?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the problem is deeper than this. The web is volatile. Any time you cite the web with a url, give the date that you accessed it.

So, if you have a date, even just a month, say, then give the url and the date.

There are resources like the [Wayback Machine](http://wayback.archive.org) that archive web sites. It might be possible that the pages you need can be found there.

Comment: It should also be possible to manually ask Wayback Machine to archive a particular URL when you access it, so that the exact version is available.